# Activiti Process Updated Variable value is not getting persisted in DB

Tags: java, activiti

I'm trying to update a Process Variable after starting a Process
When starting that activiti, I pass a random string value for the variable but I need to update the variable value afterwards.

```
System.out.println(runtimeService.getVariables(executionId));            
runtimeService.setVariable(executionId, varName, varValue);
System.out.println(runtimeService.getVariables(executionId));
```

and output is

`variableOne : "randomValue"
 variableOne : "UpdatedValue"`

But when I get documentation of the task whose documentation is

`the variable value is ${variableOne}`

I get output as

`the variable value is randomValue`

instead of

`the variable value is UpdatedValue`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the execution id is not always the same as the process instance id.
You need to update the variable against the process instance id rather than the execution id.

CHeers,
Greg